# passing values using <a href= > tag

Tags: php, google-maps

I have an array of coordinates (latitude and longitude) in one .php script and want to pass these values to maps.php which will display a google map and plot these values passed (i.e. latitude and longitude coordinates) on the map.

My question is that, is it possible to pass these values to maps.php when clicking on 
`<a href="maps.php"> view map </a>` ???

Thanks

Comment: `<a href="maps.php?lat=[theLatitude]&lng=[theLongitude]">view map</a>`

Comment: i don't see why this was voted down unless it was due to the OP not searching first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can serialize your array, and then pass it in a GET parameter. For instance:

```
# Your array of coordinates
$coord_array = array();

# Serialize the coordinates
$coord_array = serialize(coord_array);

# In your href you'd have
print '<a href="maps.php?coords=' . $coord_array . '">View Map</a>';
```

Now in your maps.php, you need to unserialize, and you can interact with the array as you normally would:

```
# Get the information from the URL
$coord_array = $_GET['coords'];

# Unserialize
$coord_array = unserialize(coord_array);

# Check the input to make sure it hasn't been changed . . .

# Now interact as you normally would with the array
print_r($coord_array);
```

This method would be ideal for passing a lot of values in a single GET parameter. If you're passing only one value, then you may be better off just setting two GET parameters, one for the longitude and one for the latitude.

Also note, that I didn't test any of this code as I didn't have time, but the concepts should be correct.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that I have two arrays for these coordinates. One for latitude and one longitude. So how will I structure this in href? Thanks

Comment: @uesr1135192 If I were you, I'd have an array of coordinates. That is, array(coord1, coord2, ...); where coord1 = array(longitude, latitude).  However with your setup, you can serialize both the longitude array, and the latitude array and just have two GET parameters (one for the longitude array, and one for the latitude array).

Comment: thanks @Louis it works! I am now trying to pass a third array array, which has the names of the places relating to the latitude and longitude coordinates passed. Should I serialize and unserialize a **String Array**? Or should I pass it to the a href straight by calling the string array variable?
Also, at the moment when I try to serialize it i get the following  error:
'Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 5 bytes'
When I don't serialize it I get get the following error:
'Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array'
Thanks

Comment: @user1135192 I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. You note that when you serialize it you get an error, which references unserializing? If you need to pass information in a similar manner to the latitude/longitude arrays, just serialize the information as before. Glad I could be of some help :)

Comment: I managed to find a fix. I had to do this:
`$lat_lng_name = base64_encode(serialize($lat_lng_name));`
and then in the receiving script:
`$lat_lng_name_array = unserialize(base64_decode($lat_lng_name_array));`
Thanks for your help @Louis! :)

Comment: Not a problem! Just for the record, I believe your fix works because base64 doesn't pass any characters that interfere with your URL. Chances are your serialization had & or something in it. Would've worked if your URL encoded the URL as well. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML do this:

```
<a href="maps.php?param1=value1&amp;param2=value2">view map</a>
```

In your PHP code you can get the values like this:

```
$param1 = $_GET['param1'];
$param2 = $_GET['param2'];
```

Read more on GET parameters in the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

Comment: That's invalid. `&param2` is not a standard character reference. You mean `&amp;`!

Comment: Sounds like the OP wants to pass multiple coordinates in the URL. Your method will likely not scale well.